# convert text to rows in r

Tags: r, regex

I have df as below and wants to convert each letter to rows.

```
df
id    text
1     ABC
2     EF
```

```
resutl
id    letters
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     E
2     F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach with `base R`

```
sp <- strsplit(data[,2], "")
out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(sp),function(x) cbind(data[x,1],sp[[x]]))))

  V1 V2
1  1  A
2  1  B
3  1  C
4  2  E
5  2  F
```

Another quick solution thanks to @Onyambu,

```
stack(with(data,setNames(strsplit(text,""),id)))[2:1] 

  ind values
1   1      A
2   1      B
3   1      C
4   2      E
5   2      F
```

**Data:**

```
data <- read.table(text="id    text
1     ABC
2     EF",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: you can also use `stack`  ie `stack(setNames(strsplit(data$text,""),data$id))[2:1]`

Comment: @Onyambu Very clean and good solution!  I think you should offer it as an answer.

Comment: just add it to yours above

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
library(tidyverse) 

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "id text
1 ABC
2 EF")

df %>%
    mutate(text = strsplit(as.character(text), "")) %>%
    unnest(text)
```

Results in:

```
  id text
1  1    A
2  1    B
3  1    C
4  2    E
5  2    F
```